# How to format currency with number format classes

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android development and i am stuck at a place. I want to format my currency, I am setting to show without decimal places and with commas.

Example: right now it's showing like `23000.00`. But I want the currency like `23,000`; how can I do that?

I tried the formatter classes but that doesn't help me.

This is how it's set now.

```
public class CurrencyFormatter {

    public static String setsymbol(BigDecimal data, String currency_symbol)
    {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(currency_symbol));
        String result=data+" "+" دينار";
        return result;
    }
}
```

I expect output to be (arabic text)23,000 instead of (arabic test)23000.00

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need a currency formatter object.

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
```

After that you can format an amount of money:

```
Double currencyAmount = new Double(23000.00);
String formattedOutput = currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount);
```

There are more options and explanations available here on Oracle's reference document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Comment: the currency is not static it could be any number.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
 format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USA"));
 String result = format.format(1234567.89);
```

This is the format set of usa you can change with your country code

reference [check description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will show in this format 23,000 without decimal points, It will show thousand separator in the number.

```
String result = null;
    try {
        // The comma in the format specifier does the trick
        result = String.format("%,d", Long.parseLong(data)); // use this result variable where you want to use.

        result = result + " " + " دينار";  // to append arabic text, do as you were doing before.

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
```

Comment: No its not. See the string result in the question. I have to use the arabic text written over there followed by the currency,which is dynamic.So please help accordingly.

Comment: Arabic word will be appended same as you were doing before. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: may be like this, result =  " دينار" + " " + result; But will remain same.

Comment: whats the reference of "data" in Long.parseLong(data) in your answer. Because its showing error when i am putting data in that parenthesis.What is data there?Kindly explain.

Comment: @AreebKhan data is your variable which is coming as parameter in your function in your code.

Comment: ohh thank you so much, but i solved the error myself.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need any other help. You are welcome.

Comment: actually i do. Can you please tell me how could I show the total count of products or items in a textview. Suppose there are 10 items stored in my wishlist , then I want to show that 10 (in integer form) in my textview field.

Comment: textview.setText(String.valueOf(your_integer));  or textview.setText("" + your_integer);

Comment: if(data.getLineItems()!=null)
            {
                count=items.getItemcounts();
            }
            else
            {
                count=0;
            }
            wishlistcount.setText(count);

this is what i am doing.Here, data is a storage field where all data is saved in one place using shared preferences."getLineItems"stores data."Count" is a string that is initially 0.So please tell accordingly.

Comment: if you are getting error at wishlistcount.setText(count);   Then please change it to wishlistcount.setText("" + count);

Comment: No i am not getting any error.But its count is not changingNo matter how many items I add in wishlist ,the textview where I am trying to show count is always zero (since it is set to zero initially).

Comment: so it means data.getLineItems() is null

Comment: problem in somewhere else

Comment: One thing I want to know is how could I find the length of "saveWishList(object);" and store the length received in a textview.

Comment: if(data.getWishList()!=null)
            {
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject((data.getWishList()));
                data.saveWishList(object);
                //wishlistcount.setText(data.saveWishList(object););
            }

I am doing this but cant able to find length of that method. and store the length received in textview named as "wishlistcount"